# Confidence Interval for E(Y0) - Linear Regression

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I'm solving exercises as preparation for a statistics exam and I'm scratching my head on the following exercise. I'll start by giving the data I have to work with:

n = 10;
x (average) = 14;
y (average) = 130;
Sxx = 2528;
Sxy = 21040;
Syy = 184730.

I have to get a confidence interval for E(Y0), considering X0 = 18, with a degree of confidence of 99%.

So first I have to get the equation y^ = â + ^b*x, which is: y^ = 13.481 + 8.3228*x.
Then substituting x with 18 I get y^ = 163.3994.

Checking the t-student table I get a t-value of 3.355 with 8 degrees of freedom.
The CI will be something like: ]163.3994 - S*3.355*(1/10 + (18 - 14)^2/2528)^0.5, 163.3994 + (...) [

I get s = (1/(8)*(Syy - 8.3228*Sxy))^0.5

The thing is, the result of this is very far from what my teacher told me it should be (]142.0079, 184.5744[).
Can you please tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The estimate of $\sigma^2$ is supposed to be $s^2=\frac1{n-2}\sum (y_i-\hat a-\hat b x_i)^2=\frac1{n-2}(S_{yy}-\hat b^2S_{xx})$. The confidence interval is then $163.2914\mp 3.355\times s\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(x_0-\bar x)^2}{S_{xx}}}$.

Comment: @BruceET The parameter to be estimated is $E(Y\mid x_0)=a+b x_0$ (this is what the OP calls $E(Y_0)$). So the standard error in question is that of $\widehat{E(Y\mid x_0)}=\hat a+\hat b x_0$.

Comment: OK. To avoid clutter, I'm deleting my previous comment. And after a while, this one.